# `ls` command not working as expected in windbg

Tags: windbg

I'm debugging a piece of code and I got it to break at an exception.  I have the relevant source and symbol paths set up, but when I use `ls`, it doesn't show or list the current source file, even when it highlights the line in the open source file I'm interested in when I select the correct stack frame.

Why is that?  What am I not understanding?  What is meant by 'current source file'?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. A stack trace or a way for someone else to reproduce would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on an address where source file is not available (like `_dbgbreakpoint` on `ntdll`) issuing `ls` will emit the message "No current source file":

```
0:000> ln @eip
(7c90120e)   ntdll!DbgBreakPoint   |  (7c901212)   ntdll!DbgUserBreakPoint
Exact matches:
    ntdll!DbgBreakPoint = <no type information>
0:000> ls
No current source file
```

`ls` by itself requires a preloaded source file using `lsf` or you need to set the `.srcpath`.

This loaded source file remains loaded until you remove it or another source file is loaded automatically by an event (i.e. if you do `.restart` and break on `_dbgbreak` and do a `ls`, it will show the stale source file that was loaded with `lsf` earlier):

```
0:000> .restart

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
0:000> ls
    77:     PAttributeHeader psecondheader = NULL ;
    78:     PAttributeHeader pthirdheader = NULL;
    79:     PFileInfoAttributeRecord pfinforecord = NULL;
    80: 
    81:     memset(&dump,0,sizeof(dump));
    82:     fopen_s( &fp,"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0", "rb" );
```

Using `lsa .` (notice the `.`) instead of `ls`, it loads the source for the current address.

The current line is denoted by `>` in the paste below .
Notice `ls` fails due to no pre loaded source file whereas `lsa .` gives you the source line.

```
0:000> g wmain

00401000 55              push    ebp
0:000> ls
No current source file
0:000> lsa .
    67: }FileInfoAttributeRecord,*PFileInfoAttributeRecord;
    68: 
    69: 
    70: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
>   71: {
```

Comment: Hi blabb. I appreciate your answers here for the WinDbg topic. You could improve the formatting of your answers a bit. Use backticks to indicate WinDbg commands within a sentence. This makes it clearer for the reader what he needs to type. Also use backticks for symbol names or module names. To emphasize something use one asterisk (italics) or two (bold). Thanks.